# Why are my flexiPages not showing up in my lighting application?

Tags: lightning-experience, scratch-org, flexipages

**TL;DR;**

My lightning app, when source-pushed to a fresh scratch org.. doesn't show any tabs for the custom page layouts. But every other editing interface in the fresh scratch org indicates they're there and associated with the app.

**Full Story**

I can create a new lightning app, with custom icon that shows in the App Launcher, and it can have a couple of custom App Pages within it, each on their dedicated tabs. Maybe throw in record-based tab for good measure, say, an 'Account' tab.

I can do all of that in scratch org #1, capture it in my SFDX project in source format. I can associate the app with an appropriate permission set, etcd.

However, if I spin up scratch org #2, and `force:source:push` what I just captured. The resulting Lightning App is in there, and after I assign the permission set.. it shows properly in the App Launcher. It may have the 'Account' tab.. but.. none of the tabs for the custom layouts (i.e. `flexipages`) seem to show up.

If I go into `Setup` > `Lightning App Builder` (which I think should be renamed to something else, but, I digress), I can see my custom flexipage layouts listed there. If I click on them, I can even see they are properly assigned to my Lightning App. 
[image]

If I go into `Setup` > `Tabs`, I can see that the scratch org recognizes the tabs exist.. there they are.

If I go into `Setup` > `App Manager`, find my lightning app and click 'Edit' on the right hand column, I can see the custom items properly assigned in the `Navigation Items` blade's `Selected Items`, just like I would expect.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I have found my issue:

In my .forceignore, I had turned off the 'profiles' business:

```
# List files or directories below to ignore them when running force:source:push, force:source:pull, and force:source:status
# More information: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_exclude_source.htm
#
**profiles
```

So, I decided to remove the `**profiles` bit from my .forceignore, and then I went into my scratch org, I added a new `Custom Tab` pointing to my custom flexiPage. Then I went into the `Lightning App Builder` > `Navigation Items` and selected the newly created tab.

Switching back to the browser tab showing my Lightning App, I hit refresh, and so I see my custom tab show up there (but still no source-pushed tab as described in my OP).

Now, I want to investigate the newly created XML metadata, so I:

```
sfdx force:source:pull
```

And now I can see the missing ingredients were in the `profiles/Admin.profile-meta.xml`:

```
<tabVisibilities>
    <tab>My Source-Pushed Tab</tab>
    <visibility>Hidden</visibility>
</tabVisibilities>
<tabVisibilities>
    <tab>My New Tab</tab>
    <visibility>DefaultOn</visibility>
</tabVisibilities>
```

The visibility was set to `hidden` on my source-pushed tab, but `DefaultOn` on the newly created tab. I belive this is due to my `Admin.profile-meta.xml` - though originally present in my project and originally had the tabs all `DefaultOn`, — I believe I ignored it from the initial push - so the org must've defaulted it to `Hidden`

So I'm happy, believing to have found the "smoking gun" - so, I try testing my theory. I update the `Admin.profile-meta.xml` so that all the hidden tabs are once again `DefaultOn` and then I issue a `force:source:push`. I was surprised that refreshing my browser did not show the immediate result I was expecting. However, launching a private/incognito window into the same org DID indeed prove that this was the fix. My tabs showed up!